# Iphone 4S screen and aux replacement costs

Tags: iphone

I smashed my phone, all the screen is completely smashed but I can still receive calls and can hear when someone messages or emails me. Also my aux plug hole is out of coordination so I can't plug in ear phones.

I just want to know how much Apple will charge to get that fixed.

Comment: We have no idea where you live, and whether Apple will consider the unit repairable. As you can see in the one good answer, a basic screen repair assumes the rest of the phone is fine, but if the metal band that makes up the iPhone 4/4S is smashes so much that you can't fit in headphones, that alone trumps a cracked glass face. I'd start with http://www.apple.com/support/contact/ if you really just want a quote from Apple on repair.

Answer (score 1):

For price quotes it's probably best to contact an Apple Store in your country directly, because prices will vary around the globe (so a quote for UK won't help you much if you live in India for example). The people in the Stores are there to help you (and are usually quite good at that) and they will also be able explain to you the difference between having your phone repaired or getting a new one.

Alternatively there might be other repair shops in your area which offer screen replacements and other services. Their prices may be lower, OTOH if more than just the screen is broken (as it seems to be in your case) they might not be able to fix your phone.